# How to make use of Homestead/Laravel dev environment on Ubuntu?

Tags: virtualbox, web-development, laravel

Basically, I'm trying to create a vagrant box on Ubuntu for development of Laravel web applications. I've done this on Windows, OS X and now I'm trying to use my Ubuntu laptop for this. I setup VirtualBox and installed Vagrant no problem but the Laravel documentation calls for this vagrant command:

```
vagrant box add laravel/homestead
```

Instead of properly setting up a box - as it does in Windows and OS X - I get an error:

```
This command was not invoked properly. The help for this command is
available below.

Usage: vagrant box add <name> <url> [--provider provider] [-h]

        --checksum VALUE             Checksum
        --checksum-type VALUE        Checksum type
    -c, --clean                      Remove old temporary download if it exists.
    -f, --force                      Overwrite an existing box if it exists.
        --insecure                   If set, SSL certs will not be validated.
        --cacert certfile            CA certificate
        --cert certfile              The client SSL cert
        --provider provider          The provider that backs the box.
    -h, --help                       Print this help
```

What is different between Ubuntu and my other systems where I have had no problem?

Please note: I do not wish to install a web stack directly onto my desktop which is why I have chosen to isolate them to virtual machines.

Laravel tutorial: http://laravel.com/docs/homestead

Answer (score 1):

what vagrant version do you have?

I've also faced this problem before and I solved it by upgrading Vagrant from version 1.0.1 to 1.6.5. After that vagrant box add laravel/homestead was running well.

Comment: Please outline exactly **how** you upgraded vagrant from version 1.0.1 to version 1.6.5 - the instructions you followed and/or the commands you used.

Comment: @Yazid Will pull up the machine today and find out what I'm using. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I simply upgraded to latest version of Vagrant (1.6.5) simply by downloading the latest .deb package from [Vagrant Downloads](https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html) and installing by running:

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/vagrant_1.6.5_x86_64.deb
```

You may be prompted to install some dependent packages.